# Creating .bat file with e-mail body in Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, batch-file, outlook-redemption

I'm currently working on a script which will read a mail from a certain sender, who will be sending some commands for the scripts to run.

### The Main Idea:

Sender sends a mail with a command for example: `ipconfig /all > result.txt` and the script running at the recipients side copies this command to a .bat file and running the .bat file to process the command.

### The Code:

```
$junk = $routlook.GetDefaultFolder(23)
$MI = $junk.items

foreach($m in $MI)
{
    if($m.SenderEmailAddress -eq '<sender-address>')
    {
        Echo "@ECHO OFF" > com.bat
        Echo $MI.item(1).Body > com.bat
        .\com.bat
    }
    break
}
```

### The Error:

[image]

Comment: I've posted a solution, but I trust you are aware of the major security risk you are running?! Email addresses can be trivially spoofed (as can anything else you might use to authenticate), so I can't see any scenario where this would be an appropriate thing to do. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not specifying the encoding of your output file.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the `Out-File` cmdlet and specify the encoding yourself. Note that the 2nd and subsequent calls to `Out-File` must specify the `-Append` parameter or you will overwrite your file.

```
$> "@ECHO OFF" | Out-File -FilePath cmd.bat -Encoding ascii
$> "Echo hi"   | Out-File -FilePath cmd.bat -Encoding ascii -Append
$> .\cmd.bat
```